# xmr-stak-cpu as a service on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. And I need to run xmr-stak-cpu as a service.
I tried to search for a possible solution, but found only for systemctl, which is on Ubuntu 16.
Is there a way/script to configure and run xmr-stak-cpu on Ubuntu 14.04 as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new upstart config

```
sudo nano /etc/init/xmrstakcpu.conf
```

Example of upstart configuration:

```
description "xmr-stak-cpu"
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo

script

        echo $$ > /var/run/xmr.pid
        exec su -s /bin/bash -c "nice -n19 /path/xmr-stak-cpu/bin/xmr-stak-cpu /path/xmr-stak-cpu/bin/config.txt" user_under_which_xmr_will_start

end script

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] Starting" >> /var/log/xmr.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/xrm.pid
    echo "[`date`] Stopping" >> /var/log/xmr.log
end script
```

Service usage:

```
sudo service xmrstakcpu start
sudo service xmrstakcpu stop
```

Comment: How do you make it a startup background service?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `upstart`? See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/351879/how-to-create-a-service-on-ubuntu-upstart/448536#448536

Upstart Example: `/etc/init/xmrstakcpu.conf`

```
# xmrstakcpu.conf
start on net-device-up IFACE=eth0
exec /usr/local/bin/xmr-stak-cpu/xmr-stak-cpu
```

This would run `/usr/local/bin/xmr-stak-cpu/xmr-stak-cpu` after the `Ethernet0`d device was initialized.

If you just want to run `xmr-stak-cpu` in background - for instance after SSH - you can use

```
nohup ./xmr-stak-cpu &
```

This will run `xmr-stak-cpu` and keep it active in background and log all output to a file `nohup.out`, while you can `logout` / `exit` SSH.

Comment: how do I run it under specific user?

Comment: You can run programs under a different user using the `su` command. But I doubt this works for services.

Comment: Under which user will it run by default?

Comment: Not sure. You can try it and after it runs you can use `ps` to see what user it is running on.